# Move node modules to vendor chunk out of app using webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have been optimizing our JS and am getting stuck on one main part. If I use the CommonChunksPlugin and create a vendor bundle it doesn't include all node modules. I then use another CommonChunksPlugin with `children: true` and it gets a bit better, but moves everything to app.js instead of vendor.js. I would like vendor to be more cacheable and larger and app to be smaller as it will change more frequently. **How can I get the node modules from app to the vendor bundle?** You can see my analyzer output and config below.

[image: Analyzer output]

And my webpack config for the plugins is:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: "underscore"
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: (module, count) => {
        var context = module.context;
        return count > 1 && context && context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      children: true,
      minChunks: 2
      // minChunks: (module, count) => {
      //   var context = module.context;
      //   return count > 1 && context && context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1
      // }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        API_ROOT_URL: JSON.stringify(settings.api_root_url),
        APP_ROOT_URL: JSON.stringify(settings.app_root_url),
        PUSHER_KEY: JSON.stringify(settings.pusher_key),
      }
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one CommonsChunkPlugin entries in my config.

```
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "common-bundle",
            filename: "common-bundle.js",
            minChunks: function (module) {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
            }
        }),
```